# How to iterate through the table using dax in power bi?

Tags: dax

I am currently working on a problem that requires iterating a table and finding the distance between the latitudes and longitudes of each entry in the table.Is there a way to iterate the table using DAX Query in Power BI?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow!! It would be great if you could [read these guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking a new question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The first hints that you have to look for are:

- add calculated columns to a table to get what you want at row level,
- use X functions such as SUMX, AVERAGEX, COUNTX (there are lots of them) to get aggregates.